# How to get the value for any key in a deeply nested json object via javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

A simple ajax call to my server is giving me this json object. How to get the value of componentName or execution time ?

```
{"data":[{"date":"20131212","time":"103053","componentName":"xxxx","qualityIndexScore":{"noOfLinesOfCode":"47,214","coverage":"61.8%","violations":{"info":"43","minor":"215","major":"19","critical":"98"}},"liveScore":{"noOfErrors":"20313","executionTime":"2938596.2450000006"},"systemHealthScore":{},"dataBaseHealthScore":{}},{"date":"20131211","time":"110504","componentName":"yyyy","qualityIndexScore":{"noOfLinesOfCode":"342","coverage":"1.8%","violations":{"info":"21","minor":"53","major":"3","critical":"2"}},"liveScore":{"noOfErrors":"462","executionTime":"9298.1225000003"},"systemHealthScore":{},"dataBaseHealthScore":{}}]}
```

Comment: `obj.data` is an array of objects.  So, the 1st one would be `obj.data[0].componentName`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends which one in the array you want. Here is the output for first set.

```
console.log(data[0].componentName);
console.log(data[0].liveScore.executionTime);
```

Second set:

```
console.log(data[1].componentName);
console.log(data[1].liveScore.executionTime);
```

and so on...